# logic if then else

Tags: php

I have a little problem concerning logical arguments

```
Year    month   day
null    +       +
null    -       +
null    +       -
nonnull -       +
```

I have translated it into code as follows

```
    if($year==null)
    {
        if($day!=null && $month!=null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        elseif($month!=null || $day!=null)
        {
            return null;            
        }            
    }
```

But I tell me that it's not correct.

[UPDATE]
- means null
+ means non-null

Comment: a) what about the case where "year" is not-null ? and b) your question is not clear - you should explain how do you translate this table as its not obvious...

Comment: No idea what you're trying to accomplish here, or what's not working.  Can you elaborate on your question please?

Comment: what means your table? It seems that nulls, pluses and minuses are all inputs. What should be your output?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($year==null || ($day!=null && $month==null))
{
    reurn null;       
}
```

If you want to return null in your cases (for example if year is null, month and day are not null (first case)) use this code. Because if I understood your question right, when year is null you want to return null anyway, and when it's not null you want to return null only if month is null and day is not.

Answer (score 0):

@mesiesta - actually you can translate all those conditions into:

```
if ($year==null) {
 if ($day==null && $month==null) {
    return "undefined";
 }
 else {
    return null;
}
```

the table doesn't "cover" a few options, one of them I showed in the code above, the other are  all the other 3 options are when year is not null